# How to inherit from a class instantiated with a builder?

Tags: python, inheritance, builder, metaclass

I have a class Document, this class is really complex to instantiate so I have a builder object to create them. Both elements are not mine, so I can't change them

Now, I want to create a subclass of Document, just to add some specific methods. In order to keep using the provided builder I tried this:

```
class SpecialDocument(Document):
     def __new__(cls, *args):
         return DocumentBuilder(*args)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #My initialization
```

The problem here is that the `__init__` method never executes cause the `__new__` method doesn't return a `SpecialDocument` (It returns a `Document`)

In my particular case I don't need to build my `SpecialDocument` differently from how I build a `Document`. Is there a way to use the same builder? If not, how can I achieve this? I just want to inherit from `Document` to add particular functionalities, maybe it could be achieved with metaclasses but I never used them (Probably cause I don't fully understand it), a little insight on them would be nice if it can help solving my problem

Comment: Do you really need a *subclass*? Can't you just use delegation to only add the behaviour that you want?

Comment: What's the relationship between `Document` and `DocumentBuilder`?

Comment: @PhilipTzou `DocumentBuilder` is an independent class that returns a new `Document` object if it's constructed without parameters or initiates it's variables if it receives a parameter (The parameter is a path to the actual document if exists)

Comment: @Bakuriu I went with the subclass option cause I have multiple `SpecialDocument`s and all of them have the `Document` behaviour in common, but if you think delegation is a better option I'd be glad to accept it

Comment: Well you could have a common class `MyBaseDocument` that contains the `Document` as an attribute and delegates to the document most functionality and then let the other specialized subclasses inherit from this one.

Comment: @Bakuriu But in this case if `Document` has a method named `write_title` then `MyBaseDocument` would need some method like `def write_title(self, *args): self.document.write_title(*args)` right? I wanted to avoid this cause there are a lot of methods, or there is some way to tell python interpreter to always call the method in `self.document` without explicitly writting it for each one? Maybe using `getattr`, but it seems a bit nasty

Comment: @Mr.E It depends. Keep in mind that you can use `__getattr__`. Something like `def __getattr__(self, name): return lambda *args: getattr(self._document, name)(*args)` could avoid having to write that kinf of methods.  The `__getattr__` method is called whenever someone does an attribute lookup *and the attribute is not found*. If a subclass then wants to provide a custom implementation it can just implement that method explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a metaclass here - you just have to proper call the superclass' `__new__` method. The way you are doing it, the instantiation of the superclass does not "know" it is being called from a subclass at all.

So, just write your code like this instead:

```
class SpecialDocument(Document):
     def __new__(cls, *args):
         return super().__new__(cls, *args)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #My initialization
```

Now, that is the ordinary way to do it - and would work if the code in your "builder" function was correctly placed inside Docment's `__new__` or `__init__`.
Since the code there does nt do that, and you can[ t pass your subclass as a parameter to the builder, a working solution might be to create a normal document, and swap its class after it has been built:

```
def special_document_init(special_document):
    ...

class SpecialDocument(Document):
    def my_special_method(self, ...):
         ...
    def overriden_method(self):
         ...
         result = super().overriden_method()
         ...

def build_special_document(*args):
    document = DocumentBuilder(*args)
    document.__class__ = SpecialDocument
    special_document_init(document)
    return document
```